# phpmyadmin insert DOB

Tags: mysql

So, I am trying to insert data in the database. I can get everything to work, except for the day of birth, which should come from POST in a select/option form. I got an answer from here where I was told to check the value of the variable and to change the database field to date. I've done the test and the data type was already date, but I still getting all O's when I try to insert in the database. Does anyone has an idea about what I am still missing?

```
$dob = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' .$_POST['day']; 

echo $dob; shows the value of the val like 1977 12 12

$insert = " INSERT INTO `vergilioDB`.`vergilioDB` (dob) VALUES ($dob)";
```

I didn't want to ask this question, but I couldn't find the solution...
Thank you very much!

Comment: When someone gives you the right answer you have to accept it. Please accept Mark's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need quotes around the value otherwise your value is interpreted as an arithmetic expression rather than a string containing a date.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vergilioDB.vergilioDB (dob) VALUES ('$dob')";
```

---

Also you should protect yourself against SQL injection - your code is unsafe.

You could for example consider using [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to ensure that the strings entered by the user are integers. Alternatively you could consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put variable within quotes

```
VALUES ('$dob')";
```